# Angular form validation class for each input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I´m currently developing an angular app with a lot of forms in it. Naturally, there is a lot of form validation involved and also a lot of set-error-class, set-success-class etc.

right now, just on input field looks like this:

```
<div 
  class="form-group"
  ng-class="{
    'has-error':
      form_provider_contact_data.company_name.$invalid && 
      !form_provider_contact_data.company_name.$pristine &&
      form_provider_contact_data.company_name.$touched,
    'has-success':
      form_provider_contact_data.company_name.$valid && 
      !form_provider_contact_data.company_name.$pristine &&
      form_provider_contact_data.company_name.$touched
  }">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="company_name">
    {{ 'LABEL_COMPANY_NAME' | translate }}
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input 
      name="company_name" 
      type="text" 
      class="form-control" 
      id="company_name"  
      placeholder="{{ 'LABEL_COMPANY_NAME' | translate }}"
      ng-model="contact_data.company_name"
      required>
    <p class="help-block">
      Bitte geben Sie einen Firmennamen an.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

With a lot of forms/inputs it´ll grow to tons of pretty similar code, which is hard to maintain. There should be a way, to create this input fields programatically, but tight now, I don´t now what would be the best way to this. 
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Some clarification: I´m looking for a way to create a Input element with the help of an template (or something similar), maybe just by setting some parameters (e.g. name/id, validations, labels and errors, etc.)

Comment: There are a lot frameworks designed for this: https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form

Comment: I think ngMessages is better than your approach. Here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure whether you are asking about validation:

> form validation class for each input

Or generating form programatically:

> there should be a way, to create this input fields programatically

**Either way something that might be useful: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages**

*(it makes managing all error conditions with form validation much more manageable, it's part of the core Angular since 1.3)*

Comment: thanks, that is already a solution to one other problem i was thinking about ;) But the main question is slightly different, I edited my question for clarification.

Comment: This one is already mentioned in the comments - http://schemaform.io/ - another similar project - https://www.forms-angular.org/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use AngularJS form validation along with Bootstrap's form validation classes. Doing it manually will create a lot of non-DRY code. So you can create generic directives for this validation.

I recently published a bower component http://sagrawal14.github.io/bootstrap-angular-validation/ to achieve the same. Check this out.